# Wrapping Backbone sync requests

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I am writing a Backbone application, and I need to offer some feedback to users whenever a request to the server is made (annoying, I know, but I have no control over this behaviour of the application). The backend always reports an informative (at least in theory) message with every response, like

```
{
  "status":"error",
  "message":"something went really wrong"
}
```

or

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "message":"congratulations",
  "data":{...}
}
```

What I would like to understand is where to put a hook for some kind of messaging service.

One possibility is the `parse()` method for models and collections. To avoid duplication, I would have to put it inside some model base class. It is still a bit annoying since all models and collections have their own `parse()` anyway.

A more reasonable place to look would be the `Backbone.sync` function. But I do not want to overwrite it, instead I would like to wrap it inside some other helper function. The problem here is that I cannot find a good hook where to put some logic to be executed with every request.

> Do you have any suggestions on how to organize some piece of logic to be executed with every request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Backbone.sync` returns whatever `$.ajax` returns, it is easy to achieve what I want by using jQuery delegates, like this

```
var originalMethod = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    var request = originalMethod.call(Backbone, method, model, options);

    request.done(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
    });
    return request;
};
```

Comment: By doing `var request = originalMethod.apply(Backbone, arguments);` instead, the code will stand a better chance of surviving an API change, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using a recent (>1.5) jquery all results from sync will return the `$.ajax` promise.
You can do it then without overriding anything in sync by using that promise. For example, if you did a fetch(), you could do:

```
var p = mymodel.fetch();
p.done(function (res) { ... });
p.fail(function (err) { ... });
```

Of course you can also use callbacks in fetch options, but I find the above much cleaner. The same pattern applies for say save or anything that uses sync.

Comment: Thank you, but this is essentially what I already answered myself. :-) I prefer to do the way I describe in my own answer, since doing what you suggest means I would have to add this behaviour for every request, which means in dozens of places.

Comment: It's fine by me ;) The advantage of the above is clarity but also the fact you can wait for all the fetches you like. For instance $.when(p1, p2, p3).then( ... initialize views... ); is by far cleaner. Customizing parse or sync is not a good place for this imho.

Comment: The fact is, every request does not mean every fetch, but also every save, delete... it soon becomes messy. Your suggestion has a point, but it is for a different use case :-)

Comment: I know this is a bit of an old post, but did the trick for me. Just to add, I am using a similar approach to above, but returning my own promise so that when the request comes back, I can globally handle a few specific response codes such as unauthorized.